# Extract an information from a JSON file with jq and set the information in a variable

Tags: json, batch-file

I want to extract an information from a JSON file called blablabla.json which look like this:

```
{
  "token": {
   "issued_at": "2018-11-04T23:35:07Z",
   "expires_at": "2018-11-05T00:35:07Z",
   "user": {
    "id": "ide",
    "name": "ide"
   }
  }
}
```

I want to get the "expires_at" date to compare it with the current date.
To do that, I use this:

`type blablabla.json|jq .token".expires_at"`

It works, but I don't know how to set it to a variable.
I try somethings like:

`SET date=type blablabla.json|jq .token".expires_at"`

but it does nothing.
Do you have an idea?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you'd use a `For /F` loop:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('type blablabla.json^|jq .token".expires_at"'
) Do Set "Expiry=%%~A"
```

Where your result can be accessed using the variable, `%Expiry%`. *(You wouldn't set a variable to the name of an important existing system variable)*.

As for checking it against the current date, you'd need to find a method of doing that as both dates would be strings, not date objects. *That is outside of the scope of this question*.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use PowerShell for this (at least as a tool) for several reasons:

1. it has direct support for json
2. it has a [datetime] type to do calculations

This one line PowerShell script returns expires.at as a day diffference from today including conversion from UTC.

```
(([datetime](Get-Content .\blablabla.json |ConvertFrom-Json).token.expires_at).Date - (Get-Date).date).Days
```

And can easily be wrapped in a batch.

```
@Echo off
For /f %%A in ('
powershell -NoP -C "(([datetime](Get-Content .\blablabla.json |ConvertFrom-Json).token.expires_at).Date - (Get-Date).date).Days"
') Do Set "Expires=%%A"
Set Expires
```

This will (for today) return:

```
Expires=0
```

and negative values for past dates, positive values for future dates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know that a .json file *should not* be processed via a Batch file for a large number of reasons. However, if the problem is simple (like this one) and there are not additional constraints, then a Batch file solution could be the simplest one, like this two-lines code that *includes* the date comparison...

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=, " %%a in ('findstr "expires_at" blablabla.json') do set "expires=%%~a"
if %expires:~0,4%%expires:~5,2%%expires:~8,2% geq %date:~6,4%%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2% goto expired
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) it's as simple as:

```
xidel -s blablabla.json -e "$json//expires_at"
```

This returns its value: `2018-11-05T00:35:07Z`.

To export this as `%expdate%`:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('xidel.exe -s blablabla.json -e "expdate:=$json//expires_at" --output-format=cmd') DO %%A
```

Xidel can also return the current date in the same format:

```
xidel -s blablabla.json -e "$json//expires_at,current-dateTime()"
```

This returns:

```
2018-11-05T00:35:07Z
2019-01-07T18:26:33.453
```